# Two almost exactly similar Pytorch neural network implementations but with consisently differing accuracies

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, resnet

Here is the implementation of a Pytorch ResNet architecture on CIFAR10 Dataset

https://github.com/Paperspace/PyTorch-101-Tutorial-Series/blob/master/PyTorch%20101%20Part%202%20-%20Building%20Neural%20Networks%20With%20PyTorch.ipynb

And here is mine

https://github.com/VishakBharadwaj94/Resnets_from_scratch/blob/master/CIFAR_Dataset_with_ResNet_from_Scratch.ipynb

Despite repeatedly reintializing my weights and training it with the SAME hyperparamters, I consistently get a lower accuracy for mine.

I cannot see any difference in the code and I am unable to figure out what is causing it

Comment: Your using `optimizer = optim.Adam(clf.parameters(), lr=0.1)` and they're using `optimizer = optim.SGD(clf.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=5e-4)` which will make a difference to the training.

Comment: Hey thanks! This just gives me another question. Isn't Adam supposed to be a superior optimization technique compared to SGD? Why does SGD do a better job in this case?

Comment: Adam is the best go to optimiser  for a lot of problems but the actual best optimiser can be any one of them, it depends on your data, model and how much time you put into tuning the hyperparameters, theirs look quite specific so I guess they've done some optimisation over which optimiser to use and with what values.